# uislder vertical in ios7-bar issue

Tags: ios7, uislider, cgaffinetransform

i want to make my UISlider Vertical.I am using Slider in IB and the below code for changing it in to vertical.

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
slider.transform = trans;
```

But i can able to see the thumb alone,not able to see the bar.
And i tried,

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
slider.layer.transform = trans;
```

getting error as

Assigning to 'CATransform3D' (aka 'struct CATransform3D') from incompatible type             'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform')

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because in the second statement you are trying to assign a CGAffineTransform transform to slider.layer.transform which is of type CATransform3D.

here is the code I use to rotate my slider

```
[self.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```